# Intermittently undo-tree aborts immediately after I CTL-P undo

Tags: spacemacs, undo-tree-mode

Intermittently, I have a problem where I start an `undo-tree-mode` with `C-X u`. And as soon as I hit `C-p` to do an undo, the `undo-tree` pane closes.

This has been happening for a long while now. It happens when I use Spacemacs master or develop and Emacs 25, 26, or 27. I've even changed my keyboard.

There are no error messages in the `*messages*` buffer.

If I toggle the select mode, I can continue my undo to completion.

I have not been able to repeat the issue on demand. I can not determine the conditions that trigger it. Its driving me crazy.

Any idea on what it is or how I could debug this?

Comment: The most likely suspect is the triggering of `undo-tree-kill-visualizer`, perhaps because you have accidentally pressed a regular key while in the working buffer when the visualizer buffer/window is open; or, perhaps you have `undo-tree-auto-save-history` in the working buffer and you have configured Emacs to auto-save the working buffer after an edit or on a timer or something.  You could set up a message inside  `undo-tree-kill-visualizer` and see if it is somehow being activated when the window suddenly closes and then check the `*Messages*` buffer.  That function is also triggered by `q`.

Comment: I finally got fed up enough to figure out how to do the experiment @lawlist suggested. I put a message in the function `undo-tree-kill-visualizer` and when the undo-tree visualizer aborts just from doing a CTRL-P or Up Arrow, the message from   `undo-tree-kill-visualizer` does show up in messages as many multiple times. `undo-tree-auto-save-history` is nil. Don't know how to debug this further.

Comment: What you describe is not the default behavior, nor is it a commonly known bug.  I have a couple of suggestions....  At the outset of `undo-tree-kill-visualizer`, place something like this `(message "last-command (%s) | current-buffer (%s)" last-command (current-buffer))` and check the message buffer to see if the keyboard shortcut you actually typed was `undo-tree-visualize-undo` or `undo-tree-visualize-redo` and see which buffer you are in when the visual buffer closes unexpectedly.  The other idea is to reduce your user-configuration to narrow down the possibilities of finding the problem.

Comment: @lawlist : I put that message function at the top of `undo-tree-kill-visualizer` and got multiple instances of `last-command (self-insert-command) | current-buffer (product.cljs)` when the undo-tree aborts. (`product.cljs` was the buffer I was editing) Really appreciate your help, this has been driving me crazy for a long time.

Comment: `undo-tree-visualize-undo` and `undo-tree-visualize-redo` jump back and forth between the working/target buffer and the visualization buffer by using `switch-to-buffer-other-window`.  This is a poor design, and should have been done using `with-current-buffer`.  Perhaps you *may* have unwittingly advised `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, or one of the functions used by the former.  A keystroke executed in the working/target buffer will cause the visualization buffer to be killed.  I would have written those functions as follows:  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/4765516cf58a1ccc1d11de63bacaff34

Comment: @lawlist Its looking like your changes may have fixed my issue. So far at least, I haven't had the issue again. Will continue to try it and see.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the proposed fix that appears to be working for you.  A few years ago, I came up with a fork (modified version) of `undo-tree` (with some help of a few forum participants) that was compatible with Emacs 25, and the change I suggested that you use is something that I have been using for several years now.  I was quite frankly in disbelief when I initially saw `switch-to-buffer-other-window` instead of `with-current-buffer` and it was one of the first things I corrected when working on the fork.

Comment: @lawlist Is there any interest in getting this into the upstream repo? I guess not many other people have this problem? Not sure why its hitting me. Again thanks!

Comment: Dr. Cubitt never responded to my first few bug reports to him personally about his original library.  I finally got his attention when I found existing bug reports in the Emacs bug tracker, and when a couple of the lead developers responded, Dr. Cubitt joined in the conversation.  I basically gave up trying to help fix Dr. Cubitt's original repo, and I just went ahead and developed my own fork.  However, my fork is only compatible with Emacs 25 -- which I'm still using, but with an updated display engine current with the 07/14/2019 master branch ... for my own feature requests that I wrote ...

Comment: @lawlist Looks like I had at least one repeat of the problem today. I'll have to double check that the patch is still there.